# LiveChart WinForms - Make YAxis start at 0

Tags: c#, winforms, axes, livecharts

I've been trying out LiveChart for c# win forms, and find it very useful. However, I'm stuck on a problem where I can't seem to get the Y-axis to start at 0. As of now it starts on 0.09999. Please see attached image.

Anyone know how to change this?

EDIT: I cant post Pictures yet… But hopefully you understand my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use an external service for now if you want to post an image, like https://imgur.com/upload and then reference that image here.